# How to implement Asp.net IdentityUser with breezejs NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, breeze

I am working with a project that leverage Breezejs and NHibernate. I implemented Asp.Net IdentityUser  in my entity model.
Anytime i tried to generate metedata, insert or update my model, using breeze NHContext. a foreign key not match exception is always thrown.  Please, how do i use Fluent mapping in my code  in order get over this NorthBreeze limitation

Comment: Are you using the [NHibernate.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/milesibastos/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity) package?  Have you addressed the problems mentioned in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243269/using-nhibernate-aspnet-identity)?  Could you provide more information about the exception that occurs?

Comment: This exception is always thrown: Could not find matching fk for property NHibernate.Identity.IdentityUserClaim.User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using NHibernate with Breeze, the foreign keys must be mapped to properties of your entity class.  That is so the foreign keys can will be available on the client.  For the IdentityUserClaim entity, you would need something like this:

```
public class IdentityUserClaim : EntityWithTypedId<int>
{
    public virtual string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public virtual string ClaimValue { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }

    // foreign key property
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; } 
}

public class IdentityUserClaimMap : ClassMapping<IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public IdentityUserClaimMap()
    {
        Table("AspNetUserClaims");
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.ClaimType);
        Property(x => x.ClaimValue);
        ManyToOne(x => x.User, m => m.Column("User_Id"));

        // foreign key mapping
        Property(x = x.UserId).Column("User_Id").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    }
}
```

Note the foreign key is mapped with `insert=false` and `update=false`.  Updates to the User_Id column go through the normal NHiberate flow (i.e. they are controlled by the related User entity).  The UserId property is used only to expose the foreign key value to Breeze.

Comment: Steve thanks for your time but i am still struggling with this issue. I am using NHibernate.Identity library which has similar implementation but not exactly the way it is above. Are you suggesting that i should  implement my own UserStore or tweak the NHibernate.Identity to have same implementation as written above. please i need ur help. I have tried to tweak the Library but still having tough time.

Comment: Wao! Thanks so much Steve. I have downloaded the source code from: http://nhibernateidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest which made it very easy for me to edit. It works now.